# Track usage of third-party application on Teams

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-teams, telemetry

How can I track how often is my company's (third-party application) is being accessed via Teams using a Telemetry in comparison to it being accessed directly on web ?

Answer (score 0):

@GirlCode:

Yes, you can manage your organization applications in the Microsoft Teams admin center.
Could you please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-apps).